# Is there a way to use less code to filter an array and transform it ready for a SWAL select?

Tags: javascript

Say you have:

```
this.group.players = [{id:1,name:'Joe Bloggs'},
                      {id:2,name:'Jane Bloggs'},
                       ...
                      ];
```

Now say you have list of all players (loaded via ajax):

```
newPlayers = [0:{id:1,name:'Joe Bloggs'},
              1:{id:2,name:'Jane Bloggs'},
              2:{id:3,name:'Jeffery Bloggs'},
              3:{id:4,name:'Jared Bloggs'},
              ...
              ];
```

The user wants to add a new player to `this.group.players`, so I'm showing them a select (using SWAL), which takes the data in the form of `value:name`. I want to skip the players that are already in `this.group.players`. So I want to end up with this:

```
selectOptions = [3:'Jeffery Bloggs',
                 4:'Jared Bloggs',
                 ...
                ];
```

Here's the code I'm using to achieve this just now:

```
  let playerIDs = this.group.players.map((player)=>{ return parseInt(player.id); });

  axios.get(route('player.index'))
       .then(async (response)=>{
               let selectOptions = response.data.reduce((result,player)=> {
                  if (playerIDs.includes(player.id)) { return result; }
                  result[player.id] = player.name;
                  return result;
               },{});
        })
        .catch( ...
```

This feels like it could be considerably improved? Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use  an `async` function as a callback to `then`.

Comment: Why do you use `parseInt`, aren't the ids numbers already?

Comment: Could you replace your square brackets with curly braces please ? It seems you are in fact using objects and it's a bit misleading

Comment: @Bergi - re async? Really? I'm using axois to pull in the array of all players, then using swal for the player to choose. If I don't use async/await I'll not be able to catch their selection?

And for the `parseInt` annoyingly no. I need to see where they are getting changed to string. Using vue so I'll need to dig around there.

Comment: @Logar I get you... this is the data as it gets to me though. `newPlayers` is actually a vue data prop (I took all the vue stuff out of the example above as I didn't think it relevant), while `playerIDs` is the data straight out of axios.

Comment: @RobertCooper Yes, really. You should not make a function `async` when it doesn't use `await`, and the code you've shown doesn't. If you want to use it, then you should also `await axios.get(route('player.index'))` instead of using `then` syntax for promises.

Comment: @Bergi thank you sir. Noted and understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the player ids and then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the player names and ids, this would give you an array with the players names and ids:

```
response.data
    .filter(({id})=> playerIDs.includes(id))
    .map(({id, name}) => {id, name})
```

You could also easily [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it by ids if you want :

```
response.data
    .filter(({id})=> playerIDs.includes(id))
    .map(({id, name}) => {id, name})
    .sort((player1, player2) => player1.id - player2.id)
```

Finally, if you want the exact format you describe in your question, that is an object with ids as keys and names as values, I believe you would have to use reduce and end up with a bit more verbose function :

```
response.data
    .filter(({id})=> playerIDs.includes(id))
    .reduce((players, player) => ({...players, [player.id]: player.name}), {})
```

Comment: oops, sorry, Seems like selectOptions is an object, not an array, so this would require some modifications, will work on it in a few minutes

Comment: Thank you sir. Appreciate the time on this. The above already looks and reads much better

Comment: Using `sort` before `reduce` makes no sense, objects don't have an order anyway

Comment: @Bergi right, I just copy pasted the last part like a dummy, thanks for the feedback